# how to separate the numbers in a string before the comma and push into an array

Tags: javascript

i have a string format like this:

```
var a=18,19,20
```

i want to seperate the numbers before comma and push them to my array which named temp:

```
  while(a.indexOf(',')>-1){
                         var x=a.split(',');
                         temp.push(x);
                     }
```

but this is all came across my mind which does not work, the string length may vary from time to time,but the format is always the same(separated with a comma)unless i get a single number which does have comma

Comment: Your use of [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is questionable, since it always splits the whole string. You basically keep pushing the same array into another endlessly. `let temp = '18,19,20'.split(',').map(Number)` looks more simple.

Comment: Is that supposed to be `var a = '18,19,20'`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes

Comment: So you don't want 20 in your final array. Is that correct?

Comment: @JavaScript you the nice one,it works